Exile in Egypt vs. Exile Now
Some time ago in the shul someone asked a question, What's the difference between exile in Mitzraim vs. exile now. Jokingly, another person made a reply which many people liked: in Mitzraim only men were slaves to pharaoh, but now both men and women are slaves to pharaoh. Indeed, the Torah speaks of the back breaking labor for the slaves and it notes a high fertility rate among the women. The midrash speaks of righteous women who sought to have Jewish children from their broken by labor husbands. It is not possible to have both high fertility and women at work as we see today in our society. Is there a source which states that most if not all Jewish women did not perform slave labor for pharaoh, although they were still enslaved?

It says in Sotah that Pharaoh tormented them by making women do men's work and vice versa.

@shmosel Where in Sota? If true, how would women have so many children. Women cannot give birth when tormented. Very few Jewish children were born during the Holocaust.

https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.11b.3?lang=bi

How do you differentiate between a miracle and reality: you firmly believe in some Exodus miracles but not that women who worked 24/7 AND delivered a sixplet every 9 months?

Seemingly the main difference is the only thing stopping nearly everyone from leaving to Israel is laziness

@shmosel perhaps few women were doing men's labor. When pregnant women lift heavy objects they miscarry.

@AlBerko Amram and Yocheved divorced so that not to have children at the times of hardship. They were free Levites.

@shmosel women get tired and broken faster than men. Yet in Egypt it seems the opposite is true. Women came to men to lift their spirits. It looks like conflicting midrashim.
